# How to organize lots of policies in BizTalk Server?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2, biztalk-rule-engine

I have a project which is using *BizTalk Server 2013 R2* in which, there's lots of policies stored in **Business Rule Composer** and it's really hard to manage and find them.

According to the business, the policies can be grouped into some categories like **Contract Policies**, **Cost Policiyes** and ...

In the **Business Rule Composer** software, there is no **Categorizing mechanism** like folders.

Questions

1. Is there any mechanism that I can use to facilitate managing and finding policies?
2. If there's not such a mechanism, is there a way to have multiple *Rule Store Databases* so I can separate them by databases?

Answer (score 2):

Policy itself is a logical grouping of similar rules. All you can do use some naming convention of policies as per your need.

Rule Store is one per BizTalk Group, so that is not an option.

Depending on how many policies you have, you can look for an option of creating your own UI to manage these policies. BizTalk provides the API Microsoft.RuleEngine which you can use to manage these policies.